# Named Default Arguments in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, default-arguments

I'm using pybind11 to wrap a C++ class method in a conversion lambda "shim" (I must do this because reasons). One of the method's arguments is defaulted in C++.

```cpp
class A
{
   void meow(Eigen::Matrix4f optMat = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity());
};
```

In my pybind code I want to preserve this optional parameter:

```cpp
py::class_<A>(m, "A")
       .def(py::init<>())
       .def("meow",
            [](A& self, Eigen::Matrix4f optMat = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity()) 
            {
               return self.meow( optMat ); 
            });
```

How do I make `optMat` an optional named argument in the generated Python code?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the docs, it is unclear how to apply them to the lambda, since the lambda arguments are _not_ instantiations (of a `py:arg` object) but type declarations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add them after the lambda:

```
py::class_<A>(m, "A")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("meow",
         [](A& self, Eigen::Matrix4f optMat) {
             return self.meow(optMat); 
         },
         py::arg("optMat") = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity());
```

Comment: Hi, will default argument `= Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity()` been called every time the python API is called ? Or it's been called only once when python module been loaded ?

Comment: @linrongbin Sorry for the late reply, but it's the latter. All the code above will only be executed once on module load. The default argument will be computed and stored in the python function object and later used as needed.